# Including Class name in POJO - JSON Marshalling

Tags: json, datatables, marshalling, jackson, resteasy

Following this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/).

GET response is:

> {
>       "singer":"Metallica",
>       "title":"Enter Sandman"
>   }

If more objects were included output should be like this:

> [{
>       "singer":"Metallica",
>       "title":"Enter Sandman"
>   }, {
>       "singer":"Elvis",
>       "title":"Rock"
>   }]

I want to get the 'classname' written too. Something like this:

> {"Track":[ {
>       "singer":"Metallica",
>       "title":"Enter Sandman"
>   }, {
>       "singer":"Elvis",
>       "title":"Rock"
>   }]}

Any simple ways to achieve this?

Looking forward to get data directly into [Datatables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html) from a JAX-RS Resteasy (Jackson) Server. Also trying to avoid DTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TrackList  
{  
   private List<Track> Track = new ArrayList<Track>();  
   // setter, getter  
}
```

GET method

```
public TrackList getTrackInJSON() {
```

**EDIT**
GET method

```
public String getTrackInJSON() {   
   // ... create list of objects  

   return convertToString(objects);  
}
```

utility method

```
static <T> String convertToString(List<T> list) throws IOException
{
    final String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(list);

    return new StringBuilder()
            .append("{\"")
            .append(list.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName())
            .append("\":")
            .append(json)
            .append("}")
            .toString();
}
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a DTO turn around

Comment: What about BadgerFish, can that be a solution?

Comment: Badgerfish has its set of nasty problems -- most developers have ran away after being bitten. Implementations are also slow.

Comment: Instead of String conversions, could just build a `Map` with entry for "Track" being value. That can be serialized as is by Jackson.

Comment: `Map<String (class name), Track>` ? Then each Track will get prefix `{"Track"`